# how to prevent any touch while keypad displayed on Iphone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm working at a .NET project using Jquery mobile and Java script, i want to prevent user from make any click when the keypad is opened which is mean that i want to disable touch outside keypad while it is opening.

Comment: Then how would someone get rid of the keypad? I usually click outside to make it go away, are you saying you would restrict this purposeful feature?

Comment: What type of keypad are you mentioning ? Is it the virtual keyboard of your mobile device ?

Comment: @TheZ yes there is a way to get red of the keypad by click on done button that is in keypad itself,so i want to make this is the only way to get rid of the keypad

Comment: @Romain  yeah that is wat i meant ,the keypad that is appear when u click on the textbox

Comment: @Ahmed From a UX standpoint it is a bad idea, once people have learned how an object works you shouldn't suddenly change it. People will get annoyed.

Comment: @TheZ i'm sorry but i'm really don't find another way to solve my issue so what do you think i should do ?

Comment: @Ahmed Well, I have no idea what your problem is because all you have requested is how to implement this particular solution. Why not edit your question to ask how to solve the real problem?

Comment: @TheZ my question is when i move from input to another input the cursor place shifted up and then get back to its normal place. and i ask this question before but no one reply me , so do u have any idea about this issue

Comment: i have a picture shows my issues but i can't upload it because i need 10 reputation and i have now 8 :)